# How to keep React js out of the global scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React js and I am a little bit confused.

I thought that modules would keep Web app variables in a local scope, but apparently not. React still creates globals such as window.React.

Am I missing something? Is it possible to keep React in a local scope?

My use case: I am creating a Web portal that will aggregate React-based third party widgets from multiple sources. Each widget has its own version of React and I want to make sure there is no interference.

[Edit] Some of the widgets load React from a CDN, could this make a difference? Apart from looking for window.React, are there other tests I could/should run in the global scope?

Comment: Depends on how you are packaging your app. If you are using something like webpack it should package everything into your output file and shouldnt declare/define anything into the global space. Unless your code explicitly set it or your webpack or other packaging library was set to expose them. Otherwise if you are directly including react, eg `<script src="react.js">` then its going to automatically assign React to global space

Answer (score 1):

When you use imports global scope should be untouched. There must be something wrong with your setup:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/epic-mclaren-vzo2x